# Drools Planner set minimalAcceptedSelection at runtime

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I can set the minimalAcceptedSelection editing SampleDroolsConfig.xml

```
        ...
        <acceptor>
            <solutionTabuSize>1000</solutionTabuSize>
            <planningEntityTabuSize>7</planningEntityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <minimalAcceptedSelection>200</minimalAcceptedSelection>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>   
</solver>
```

Is it possibile to set this parameter at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
XmlSolverFactory solverFactory = new XmlSolverFactory(SOLVER_CONFIG);
LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig localSearchSolverPhaseConfig = (LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig) solverFactory.getSolverConfig().getSolverPhaseConfigList().get(1);
localSearchSolverPhaseConfig.getForagerConfig().setMinimalAcceptedSelection(200);
```

See the Drools Planner manual section about configuration by Java (instead of XML).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. Another question: is it possible to dynamically change, during the scheduling process, the minimal accepted selection value? The reason is that for the first minutes I want to have a low value to improve faster the current solution, then I want to explore more solutions increasing the minimal accepted selection value.

Comment: I am planning for such a feature in the future. Meanwhile, extend the Accepted*Forager (see manual on how to use a custom forager) and hook it in there.